# Какие есть способы узнать пароль от windows через консоль, когда ты в системе?

Tags: python, windows

Хочу написать простенький скрипт, чтобы узнавать пароль системы и выводить его на экран

Comment: Почему Вы решили, что сможете это сделать?

Comment: Пароли в Windows по-моему последний раз можно было узнать когда Win NT хакнули, с тех пор всё надёжно спрятано и в явном виде пароль нигде не хранится, его можно только сбросить, а подсмотреть никак нельзя.

Comment: Igor, В данной сфере нет ничего невозможного

Answer (score 3):

Так как в вопросе указано, что скрипт должен быть простым, можно сделать это, как было показано в одном фильме.

В Вашем скрипте выполните системную команду

```
grant access to passwords
```

В ответ будет выведено (большими зелеными буквами)

```
ACCESS GRANTED
```

Следующим шагом выполните команду

```
get current user password
```

Система выведет пароль, который Вам нужно перенаправить в переменную или в файл.

Comment: компьютер Summit можна взять этим? или там стоит усиленная защита? ничего что там Linux?

Comment: Я искал консольные команды, для определения забытого пароля от windows, когда человек уже в системе

Answer (score 0):

Вот что нашел в поиске:

Passwords are not encrypted and stored. Password algorithms (exactly how this works is algorithm specific) encrypt some number of zeros some number of times (rounds). Your password is used as a key for this encryption, additionally a string is added to your password for the encryption, call a salt. (The salt is stored with the password) in the /etc/shadow file (usually) The salt makes sure that two users using the same password results in a different hash in the shadow file.

When you log in, the system takes the password you provide and along with the salt repeats the encryption and compared it to the stored hash.

**So the answer is you cannot find the user password on the system, they are not stored in the system, only the hash.**

Проще говоря, в системе самого пароля нет, и получить ты его никак не сможешь

**UPD**

Источник:

https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-find-users-password-on-my-computer-using-command-prompt?share=1

**UPD 2**

Вот это точно для `Windows`

All the user account details in windows os is stored in sam (security account manager). This file is located in c:\windows\system32\config folder. But this folder is not accessible while the os is booted up. So I think you got your answer by now. As you can open command prompt only when windows is running and during this period you can not access the sam file.

There are other means by which you can look into sam file. You can do this only before booting into your primary os. You can use other bootable os or softwares to access it.

But even if you entered the sam folder, you won't be able to read the password as the passwords are not stored as plain text. The passwords first go through one way encryption and they are stored in LM/NTLM hashes. You can only obtain these hashes. After that it is your job how you crack them.

Comment: Windows и путь /etc/shadow как-то не очень сочетаются.

Comment: Это пример, там сто процентов про винду было написано.

Comment: Сто процентов про линукс/юникс. Это там ясно из последнего абзаца.

Comment: Я так понимаю, сути это не меняет. Что там что там нет паролей, есть только хеши

Comment: Пожалуй, лучший ответ на мой вопрос, спасибо